# Sum unique values based on criteria from another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data set. I am trying to figure out how to sum "Sales" of each unique "Product ID" for the respective "Fiscal Year".

Desired result:

[image]

So far I have tried

```
=SUM(FILTER(F2:F,COUNTIFS(C2:C,C2:C,ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C))=1))
```

but that doesn't factor in the fiscal year criteria, so just wondering if anyone has an idea how to incorporate that part into my formula.

[image]

Link to [sample data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HU6ZjlyPiH33q-mZNXeyWwQqseYtA0aOBNE1RZfjEt4/edit#gid=0)

Comment: the sheet you've shared is private. Please update the sharing settings to Anyone with the link -> EDITOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QUERY()` function with `pivot` clause. Try-

```
=QUERY(A2:F,"select C, sum(F) where C is not null group by C pivot E")
```

If you need to format sum result as currency then include `format` clause.

```
=QUERY(A2:F,"select C, sum(F) where C is not null group by C pivot E format sum(F) '$0,0'")
```

And to filter years you can add another criteria to `where` cluase.

```
=QUERY(A2:F,"select C, sum(F) where (E<=2020) and (C is not null) group by C pivot E format sum(F) '$0,0'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. Although it provides the sum I am looking for, I am technically looking for one overall sum instead of dividing the sales number by Product ID. 

So like:

2019         |    2020
$123456   |   $123456

Is that possible with the query function?

Comment: Would you please then try `=QUERY(A2:F,"select E, sum(F) where (E<=2020) and (E is not null) group by E format sum(F) '$0,0'")`.

Comment: @Ludicium Use simple `=SUMIFS($F:$F,$E:$E,H2)`. See your sheet. I have put the formula for you.